# Keeping track of Django package updates

Tags: python, django, pypi

My Django application currently depends on quite a few Python and Django libraries and packages.

I was wondering if there is an admin application that allows you to keep track of all the latest updates to packages on PyPi. This would be really convenient as it would allow you to keep an eye on updates which sometimes might be quite crucial i.e. security patches.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pip-review.

https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools

Here's the description from the site:

> checks PyPI and reports available updates. It uses the list of currently installed packages to check for updates, it does not use any requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

Pip can do more than you think. Simply:

```
pip list -o
```